# Help me find a question on multiple measurements of the same quantity

Tags: discussion, support

I'm quite sure this question

[A better estimator than average?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320873/a-better-estimator-than-average)

(whose title is not very appropriate, btw) is a duplicate. I suggested closing it as a duplicate of this one:

[Two measurement devices vs 1 device multiple measurements](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314915/two-measurement-devices-vs-1-device-multiple-measurements)

which seems appropriate to me. However, this isn't the question I had in mind when I thought it was a duplicate. The question I'm looking for should be from this year, about two different measurements (maybe two different instruments) of a same unknown quantity, formulated in terms of random variables (if I remember correctly). I tried using CV search and Google, without success. Can you help me?

**EDIT** I recall the question had an answer (or at least a long comment, but I think it was an answer) which said something like "you need to make some assumptions or you can't say anything  about which is the more accurate instrument, because infinite combinations of different errors in the two instruments could give exactly the same measurements.

Comment: Hint: try clicking the “ask question” button; write something in the body, then click the title box and search there. It has been reported (I’d need to search where it was reported) it searches better than the search box (this was some years ago; perhaps they already improved the search box too). Give it a try.

Comment: Was it any of [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=sensors%20average%20is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017)?

Comment: @gung it was none of those, and even substituting *average* with *two* didn't help. I'm starting to think it was deleted.

Comment: @AndreSilva good tip! I'm not at at a pc anymore, and the smartphone interface is severely limited, but next year :-) I'll try your suggestion too. Happy New Year to everyone!

Comment: @AndreSilva I tried, and while it did give me better suggestions than the search box, I still couldn't find what I was looking for. Maybe it had been deleted.